# access object value in the same object in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'd like to access the object value in the same object and use it, is this possible?
If not, what else could I do to make something like this work?

```
  const languages = [
      {
        langCode: "cs",
        countryCode: getCountryInfoByLanguage(this.langCode).countryCode,
        language: LanguageValueToName(this.langCode)
      },
```